# Proving $f(t) = \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)}{3^{n\alpha}}$ is Lipschitz

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

I have a homework problem which consists of two parts, the first of which I have been staring at for several days with very little (constructive) progress.

I need to show that the function $$f(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)}{3^{n\alpha}}\in\Lambda^{\alpha}$$ when $0 < \alpha \leq 1$.  The second part is to show that if $\alpha < \beta < 1$, then $f\notin\Lambda^{\beta}$, but I'll worry about the second part later.

I tried considering 
$
\begin{eqnarray*}
|f(t+h) - f(t)| &=& \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}(t + h))}{3^{n\alpha}} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|\\
&=& \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t + 3^{n}h)}{3^{n\alpha}} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|\\
&=& \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)\cos(3^{n}h) - \sin(3^{n}t)\sin(3^{n}h)}{3^{n\alpha}} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|\\
&=& \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)\cos(3^{n}h) - \sin(3^{n}t)\sin(3^{n}h)}{3^{n\alpha}} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|\\
&=& \left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)\cos(3^{n}h) - \sin(3^{n}t)\sin(3^{n}h) - \cos(3^{n}t)}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|\\
&\leq& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{\cos(3^{n}t)\cos(3^{n}h) - \sin(3^{n}t)\sin(3^{n}h) - \cos(3^{n}t)}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|\\
\end{eqnarray*}
$

EDIT:  Removed the last half - dozen lines which turned out to be completely non-constructive.

Now I'm not sure if I'm even remotely close to going down the right path, but if I could get this manipulated into something of the form $C^{\alpha}$ I'd be done.  But I just can't seem to go any further.   Any suggestions?

Comment: Since your geometric series starts at $n=1$, the sum is$$\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^\alpha}{1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^\alpha}$$ but you've still lost your $h$.

Comment: Right.  In fact the $h$ was lost a long time ago.  So taking the $sin/cos$ functions and bounding them by $1$ is going too far I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Mean Value Theorem on the terms with $n<N$:
$$
\begin{align}
|f(t+h)-f(t)|&\le\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\frac{\cos(3^n(t+h))-\cos(3^nt)}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\left|\frac{3^nh\sin(3^n(t+\eta_n))}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|+\sum_{n=N}^\infty\left|\frac{\cos(3^n(t+h))-\cos(3^nt)}{3^{n\alpha}}\right|\\
&\le|h|\frac{3^{N(1-\alpha)}-3^{1-\alpha}}{3^{1-\alpha}-1}+2\frac{\frac{1}{3^{N\alpha}}}{1-\frac{1}{3^{\alpha}}}\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Choose $N$ so that $|h|\sim3^{-N}$.  Then $|h|3^{N(1-\alpha)}\sim|h|^\alpha$ and $\frac{1}{3^{N\alpha}}\sim|h|^\alpha$.  Thus, the right side of $(1)\sim|h|^\alpha$.

To be more precise, let $N=\lfloor\log_3(\frac{1}{h})\rfloor$. Then $|h|3^{N(1-\alpha)}\le|h|^\alpha$ and $\frac{1}{3^{N\alpha}}\le3|h|^\alpha$. Thus,
$$
|f(t+h)-f(t)|\le\left(\frac{1}{3^{1-\alpha}-1}+\frac{6}{1-\frac{1}{3^{\alpha}}}\right)|h|^\alpha\tag{2}
$$
Note that the $\Lambda_\alpha$-norm in $(2)$ blows up near $\alpha=0$ and $\alpha=1$.

Comment: Very nice! [For the sake of completeness...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function)

Comment: I think I see where you're going - thank you for this.  Can you explain what you mean by $\sim$?

Comment: Instead of $\frac{3^{N(1 - \alpha)} - 3^{1-\alpha}}{3^{1-\alpha} - 1}$, I get

$\frac{3^{N(1-\alpha)} - 1}{3^{1-\alpha} - 1}$.

Comment: @Kyle: are you summing from $n=0$ or $n=1$?

Comment: Ahh..  I was doing $0$; but should have be summing from $1$.  Thank you.

Comment: OK I FINALLY have worked through the details.  I will mention on my assignment that this was not my idea.

Thanks again.  I never would have figured this out.

Comment: @robjohn: How do you deal with the $3^{1-\alpha}$ term in the first fraction?

Comment: @Kyle: if something is less than $\displaystyle\frac{3^{N(1-\alpha)}-3^{1-\alpha}}{3^{1-\alpha}-1}$ it is certainly less than $\displaystyle\frac{3^{N(1-\alpha)}}{3^{1-\alpha}-1}$, so there is really nothing with which to deal.

Comment: Well when you put it like that, how can I disagree?  :P

I guess I'm just so used to working with things between $|\cdot|$ signs that I imagine them there when they aren't.

Thanks again.